# C++ Is there a way to get template types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a map visitor that's templated like this

```
template <class Map> class MyVisitor : public MyMapVisitor<Map>;
```

With Map being necessarily an std::map

And I want to have a method in it that I would like to create a list of all the members stored in my map as such:

```
std::vector <Map::*second_template_argument*> toList ();
```

Is there a way to do this? Because I'm not allowed to change the MyMapVisitor superclass but I can change the MyVisitor subclass.

Comment: From what you've shown, `Map` doesn't have any template parameters.

Comment: It's an std::map, but it's templated in a way that i dont have to pass a whole bunch of template parameters

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho You typically do not have to *pass a whole bunch of template parameters* to `std::map`, just the key type and mapped type

Comment: Did you try void pointer? `void *yourMapType;`

Comment: You have no idea how big the code gets when i template the map parameters instead of the map.

Answer (score 8):

For a std::map you have three options:

- std::map::value_type, which is a key/value pair
- std::map::key_type for the key
- std::map::mapped_type for the mapped value.

Comment: Quick warning to the newcomer, often times you have to prepend using these types with a 'typename'.

Answer (score 1):

For the more general case, if the class isn't kind of enough to provide typedefs for its template types, you can use `decltype` (if you have C++11). For your `map` example, you could do this:

```
std::map<int, double> myMap;

typedef decltype(myMap.begin()->second) valueType; // double
std::vector<valueType> myVector;
```

Note that `myMap.begin()` is not actually *called* by this code; the `decltype` expression simply evaluates to whatever type `myMap.begin()->second` *would have* returned (which is `double` in this case).

Obviously it's nicer to rely on the typedefs when you have them!

Comment: Note that this requires you to know what type the map's keys are.  You'll get an error, for example, if the key type is `std::string` and you try to do `decltype(myMap[0])`.

Comment: @dlf [Try it with `myMap[1]`](https://ideone.com/mTteTn). Looks like 0 was treated as a null pointer and implicitly converted to `std::string`.

Comment: @T.C. Ah; I completely misunderstood what @Maxpm meant. I will update my answer to use `begin()` instead.

Comment: Problem is I don't have C++11

Answer (score 0):

No. What you're describing is the ability to pass not a type but a member of the class. That can be passed at run time but there's no way to pass the name of a member as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. The first is to make the implmenetation a specialization.

```
template <class MapType> class MyVisitor;

template <class T, class J>
class MyVisitor<Map<T,J>>: public MyMapVisitor<Map<T,J>>
{
  std::vector<J> toList();
}
```

I personally don't like this one, but sometimes it is all you've got.

The second is to expose the type via a public typedef (the way vector does):

```
template <typename T, typename J>
struct MyMap
{
  typedef T sometype;
  typedef J someothertype;
}
```

And then

```
std::vector<Map::someothertype> toList();
```

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho I'll leave my answer up as a general solution, but I wrote my answer before I learned it was std::map. std::map has already implemented option 2. Dieter's answer above is much more salient.